# Can't spy on injected services' method in angular 4

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I am trying to spy and intercept a method of service I use in the component I am trying to unit test:

This is the component I am trying to test:

```
export class SearchModuleCheckCardListComponent implements OnInit {
    httpError: boolean = false;


  constructor(private searchModuleService: SearchModuleService) {
    console.log("Constructor");
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.fetchSearchModule();
  }



  /**
   * Get all search modules from the back end service
   */
  fetchSearchModule() {
    console.log("FetchSearchModule");
    this.searchModuleService.fetchSearchModules().subscribe(searchModules => 
    {
      //Most code abstracted out for simplicity
      this.httpError = false;
    }, err => {
      this.httpError = true;
    })
  }
```

Basically what I am trying to test is that the property **httpError** is set , this is what my spec file looks like : (again stripped out irrelevant code)

```
describe('SearchModuleCheckCardListComponent', () => {
  let component: SearchModuleCheckCardListComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<SearchModuleCheckCardListComponent>;
  let searchModuleService: SearchModuleServiceStub;



  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [
                      SearchModuleCheckCardListComponent,
                    ],
      providers:    [
                      { provide: SearchModuleService, useClass: SearchModuleServiceStub },
                    ]
    })
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(SearchModuleCheckCardListComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    searchModuleService = fixture.debugElement.injector.get(SearchModuleService);
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

it('should set httpError on error', () => {
    spyOn(searchModuleService, 'fetchSearchModules').and.returnValue(Observable.throw('error'));

    //'Trying to test:'expect(component.httpError).toBeTruthy();

    //This fails  inspite of fetchSearchModules being called in the stub
    expect(searchModuleService.fetchSearchModules).toHaveBeenCalled();
  })
});
```

This is what searchModuleServiceStub looks like:

```
export class SearchModuleServiceStub {


  constructor() {}


  fetchSearchModules(): Observable<SearchModule[]> {
    console.log('fetchSearchModules Called');
    return Observable.of(SEARCH_MODULES);
  }
}
```

Now the console does log out '`fetchSearchModules Called`' when I run the test, but the spy still doesn't seem to intercept the function call

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because the `ngOnInit()` life-cycle hook is fired before you create your spy. Therefore the function has been called without the spy knowing about it.

You have two options: 
1) Re-fire `ngOninit()` in your test after your spy creation. 
2) Create your spy **before** you call `TestBed.createComponent()` in your `beforeEach()`

Answer (score 1):

Seems like I had to explicitly call ngOnInit(); This is what I did to makes it work:

```
 it('should set httpError on error', () => {
    spyOn(searchModuleService, 'fetchSearchModules').and.returnValue(Observable.throw('error'));
    component.ngOnInit();
    expect(component.httpError).toBeTruthy();
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

Try switching to `TestBed.get(SearchModuleService)` you do not need to get it off of the `debugElement`.

Answer (score 0):

The call to `fixture.detectChanges` is getting in the way of your ngOnInit testing.  From the Angular Testing Guide:

> Delayed change detection is intentional and useful. It gives the tester an opportunity to inspect and change the state of the component before Angular initiates data binding and calls lifecycle hooks.

So, by the time you get to setting the spy, ngOnInit has already been called, and your test won't re-call it.  That's why your extra call to ngOnInit causes it to work.

Moving the `fixture.detectChanges()` call to after the spy setup should let your test work correctly, and be a more correct test.

Comment: Same kind of issue, but in my case I am using InjectionToken (i.e. interface) instead of the concrete class. Any suggestions !!!

Answer (score 0):

Use jasmine's [`toThrowError`](https://jasmine.github.io/2.0/introduction.html#section-Spies:_%3Ccode%3Eand.throwError%3C/code%3E) Spy method.

```
// Previously, declare this
let spy: jasmine.Spy;

it('should set httpError on error', () => {
  spy = spyOn(searchModuleService, 'fetchSearchModules')
    .and.throwError('error retrieving data');

  // Error handling check
  expect(spy).toThrowError('error retrieving data');
  expect(component.httpError ).toBeTruthy();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your issues seems to be related to the fact that you haven't injected the service in the test in order to spy, refactor your test like this

```
it('should set httpError on error', inject([SearchModuleService], (searchModuleService: SearchModuleService) => {
     spyOn(searchModuleService, 'fetchSearchModules').and.returnValue(Observable.throw('error'));

     //'Trying to test:'expect(component.httpError).toBeTruthy();

    //This fails  inspite of fetchSearchModules being called in the stub
     expect(searchModuleService.fetchSearchModules).toHaveBeenCalled();
   })
}));
```

Let me know if works